# How to simply parse html references

Tags: c++, html, parsing, html-parsing

how it is possible ,to simply parse html links. For example I receive http response containing http. In which you have links to other files, which need to be downloaded for example jpgs, css files,js files. What is the simplest way to parse all this references.

Comment: If you need it in c++, then tag it c++ the next time... oh and you should **totally** try regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @ivo, you suggest regex and point to the bane of parsing html with regex .. *hmmm..*, are you missing a **not** in there ?

Comment: @Gaby Doesn't the link itself stand for sarcasm? :)

Comment: @Ivo - and those who _don't_ follow the link? Do you think _they_ will get the sarcasm?

Comment: @Ivo, wasn't sure but truth is that new members might not get it ... (*you did not have a single smiley .. :p*)

Answer (score 1):

Use an HTML parser for your platform/language.

There are some recommendations for c++ ones [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489522/library-recommendation-c-html-parser).

Once you have a parsed document, you will need to look at each `src` and `href` in it - you will also need to remember the `base` tag, if one exists and add logic for external, relative and absolute paths.